# If my makefile rule changes directories, does it need to change back before finishing?

Tags: makefile, semantics

If I have a rule in my makefile like this:

```
subdir/object:
    cd subdir && do_stuff_to_build_object
```

Do I need to add `&& cd ..` to the end of the rule, so that `make` ends up in the same directory at the end of running it as it started? Or does `make` run the rule in a subshell or otherwise shield itself from things like changing directories? In other words, after executing that rule, will subsequent rules be executed in `subdir/` instead of where I want them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on Unix-based systems.

The action is performed by a shell (or, at least, a sub-process) run by `make`, and any `cd` operations that it performs do not affect the parent `make` process.